# Malloc shouldn't return NULL on this struct instantiation

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, malloc, doubly-linked-list

I'm working on a challenge problem themed about graphs, so I decided to implement a multiply linked list (this data structure can represent directed graphs). I'm running into problems when I try to create nodes for the list. The program compiles fine, but when it runs it only goes to a certain point and exits without warning. Running it in debug mode within VS2019, the IDE shows me I'm trying to dereference a null pointer. In fact, before it even compiles it underscores the suspicious line and warns that that could happen. But I don't understand why at all. Here is the implementation of the linked list (with minimal working example, and do mean *minimal*, I tried my best...):

```c
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

typedef unsigned int uint;

typedef struct Node {
    uint id;
    uint data;
    size_t num_parents;
    size_t size_parents;
    struct Node * parents;
    size_t num_children;
    size_t size_children;
    struct Node * children;
} Node;

/*/ ORIGINAL PROBLEMATIC REALLOCATING FUNCTION
Node * reallocate_node_array(Node * array, size_t* size) {
    Node * new_array = new_array(Node, *size * 2);  // this doesn't seem to be working as I expected
    for (size_t i = 0; i < *size; i++) {
        new_array[i] = array[i];                    // FAULTY LINE
    }
    *size *= 2;
    return new_array;
}
/**/
//NEW VERSION EDITED TO REFLECT CRAIG ESTEY'S COMMENTS AND ANSWER
Node * reallocate_node_array(Node * array, size_t* size) {
    array = realloc(array, (*size) * 2);
    if (array == NULL) {
        perror("realloc");
        exit(1);
    }
    *size *= 2;
    return array;
}

void remove_node(Node * array, size_t * size, size_t index) {
    for (int i = index; i < *size - 1; i++) {
        array[i] = array[i + 1];
    }
    (*size)--;
}

void remove_parent (Node * node, uint id) {
    for (int i = 0; i < node->num_parents; i++) {
        if (node->parents[i].id == id) {
            remove_node(node->parents, &node->num_parents, i);
        }
    }
}

void remove_child(Node * node, uint id) {
    for (int i = 0; i < node->num_children; i++) {
        if (node->children[i].id == id) {
            remove_node(node->children, &node->num_children, i);
        }
    }
}

void add_child(Node * node, Node * child) {
    if (node->num_children >= node->size_children) {
        node->children = reallocate_node_array(node->children, &node->size_children);
    }
    node->children[++node->num_children] = *child;
}

void add_parent(Node * node, Node * parent) {
    if (node->num_parents >= node->size_parents) {
        node->parents = reallocate_node_array(node->parents, &node->size_parents);
    }
    node->parents[++node->num_parents] = *parent;
}

int main() {
    char * file_name = "input.txt";

    FILE * data_file = fopen(file_name, "r");
    if (data_file == NULL) {
        printf("Error: invalid file %s", file_name);
        return 1;
    }

    uint num_nodes, num_relationships;

    fscanf(data_file, "%u %u\n", &num_nodes, &num_relationships);

    // I'm sorry that I'm not checking for the result of malloc in this block.
    // I promise I'll be more responsible in the future.
    Node * nodes = (Node*)malloc((num_nodes + 1) * sizeof(Node));
    for (size_t i = 1; i <= num_nodes; i++) {
        nodes[i].id = i;
        fscanf(data_file, "%u ", &nodes[i].data);
        nodes[i].num_children = 0;
        nodes[i].size_children = 10;
        nodes[i].children = (Node*)malloc(10 * sizeof(Node)); // FAULTY LINE #1
        nodes[i].num_parents = 0;
        nodes[i].size_parents = 10;
        nodes[i].parents = (Node*)malloc(10 * sizeof(Node));  // FAULTY LINE #2 
    }

    for (uint i = 0; i < num_relationships; i++) {
        uint parent_id, child_id;
        fscanf(data_file, "%u %u\n", &parent_id, &child_id);

        add_child(&employees[parent_id], &employees[child_id]);
        add_parent(&employees[child_id], &employees[parent_id]);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Where it says "FAULTY LINE #1" and "#2", the debugger tells me the program has reached a breakpoint (throws an exception).

The point of the main function is to build the following structure (graph):
[A directed graph with small number of nodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sm3O7.png). The most succint way to do that is by reading instructions from a file. Here is the content of `input.txt`:

```
7 8
21 33 33 18 42 22 26
1 2
1 3
2 5
3 5
3 6
4 6
4 7
6 7
```

First line: 7 is the number of nodes; 8 is the number of connections (relationships).
All other lines: Left number is parent node; right number is child node.

So, my problem *was* that I couldn't get past the `reallocate_node_array` function and later from "FAULTY LINE #1" and "#2".

#### EDIT

---

So I edited a lot above in order to provide a minimum working example and further clarify my context and difficulties. Whatever else I was doing wrong, I would appreciate if you'd tell me.

However, after I edited my `reallocate_node_array` function according to Craig Estey's critique, I was able to move further along in debugging and realized some terrible faults in the above implementation. Most importantly is that my struct `Node`'s fields `parents` and `children` needed to be of type `Node**` and not `Node*`, because they're supposed to be arrays in order to represent a **multiply-linked list**. With that in mind, I rewrote the implementation as below, which **is behaving as expected**. I ran, nevertheless, into problems with further tasks using this code, which are not in the scope of this question. If I'm to pose a new question, I'll be sure to keep all of your critiques in mind and try to write a good question next time.

Thank you all for all your feedback.

```c
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

typedef unsigned int uint;

typedef struct Node {
    uint id;                // identifier of the node
    int data;               // actual data
    size_t num_parents;     // actual number of parent nodes
    size_t size_parents;    // current maximum capacity of array of parent nodes
    struct Node** parents;  // all nodes that connect from "upstream"
    size_t num_children;    // actual number of child nodes
    size_t size_children;   // current maximum capacity of array of children nodes
    struct Node** children; // all nodes that connect "downstream"
} Node;

void reallocate_node_array(Node** array, size_t* size) {
    array = realloc(array, sizeof(Node*) * (*size) * 2);
    if (array == NULL) {
        perror("realloc");
        exit(1);
    }
    *size *= 2;
}

// The intention is to pass `num_children` or `num_parents` as `size` in order to decrease them
void remove_node(Node** array, size_t* size, size_t index) {
    for (size_t i = index; i < *size - 1; i++) {
        array[i] = array[i + 1];
    }
    (*size)--; // the decrement to either `num_children` or `num_parents`
}

void remove_parent(Node* node, uint id) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < node->num_parents; i++) {
        if (node->parents[i]->id == id) {
            remove_node(node->parents, &node->num_parents, i);
        }
    }
}

void remove_child(Node* node, uint id) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < node->num_children; i++) {
        if (node->children[i]->id == id) {
            remove_node(node->children, &node->num_children, i);
        }
    }
}

void add_parent(Node* node, Node* parent) {
    if (node->num_parents >= node->size_parents) {
        reallocate_node_array(node->parents, &node->size_parents);
    }
    node->parents[node->num_parents++] = parent;
}

void add_child(Node* node, Node* child) {
    if (node->num_children >= node->size_children) {
        reallocate_node_array(node->children, &node->size_children);
    }
    node->children[node->num_children++] = child;
}

int main() {
    char* file_name = "input.txt";

    FILE* data_file = fopen(file_name, "r");
    if (data_file == NULL) {
        printf("Error: invalid file %s", file_name);
        return 1;
    }

    uint num_nodes, num_relationships;
    fscanf(data_file, "%u %u\n", &num_nodes, &num_relationships);

    Node* nodes = (Node*)malloc((num_nodes + 1) * sizeof(Node));
    for (size_t i = 1; i <= num_nodes; i++) {
        nodes[i].id = i;
        fscanf(data_file, "%u ", &nodes[i].data);
        nodes[i].num_children = 0;
        nodes[i].size_children = 10;
        nodes[i].children = (Node**)malloc(10 * sizeof(Node*));
        for (size_t j = 0; j < 10; j++) nodes[i].children[j] = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
        nodes[i].num_parents = 0;
        nodes[i].size_parents = 10;
        nodes[i].parents = (Node**)malloc(10 * sizeof(Node*));
        for (size_t j = 0; j < 10; j++) nodes[i].parents[j] = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    }

    for (uint i = 0; i < num_relationships; i++) {
        uint parent_id, child_id;
        fscanf(data_file, "%u %u\n", &parent_id, &child_id);
        
        add_child(&nodes[parent_id], &nodes[child_id]);
        add_parent(&nodes[child_id], &nodes[parent_id]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *I use this define for shorthand:  `#define new_array(type, size) type*)malloc(size*sizeof(type))`*  Get rid of that.  Then figure out why things blow up with it in place...

Comment: First, check if `malloc` returns `NULL`. So what is the value of `*size` at the time of allocation?

Comment: Where is the _call_ to `reallocate_node_array`? Please _edit_ your question and post it. If it's (e.g.): `myarray = reallocate_node_array(myarray,&myarray_size)`, then the _original_ value of `myarray` is leaked (because the function does _not_ `free` the old/original array pointer). Unless you're trying to create a separate _duplicate_ copy, why not just use `realloc`?

Comment: I got rid of the #define as @AndrewHenle suggested, and I'm getting a different error that could be unrelated to the question. I'm investigating right now.

Comment: @CraigEstey `realloc` is probably the best way. I come from a C++ world and an not very experienced in C, so I'm trying to practice, that's why I did it this way. I didn't know `realloc` had a different effect. The call to `reallocate_node_array` is like this: `node->children = reallocate_node_array(node->children, &node->size_children);`

Comment: If you end up posting a new question, make sure to construct a minimal example program to reproduce it.  When you rip out bits of code and show them out of context, it's hard to provide a real analysis.  One other point about your `reallocate_node_array` function is it apparently is leaking `array` -- is it supposed to `free` that?  You don't show anywhere how it's being used.

Comment: Yup, that's a/the leak.

Comment: @KamilCuk `*size` is supposed to be the total size of the array of nodes stored in either the `children` or `parents` attribute of `Node`.

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre]. In particular, show the value of `*size` when `reallocate_node_array` is called.

Comment: Do you ever allocate a size of zero?

Comment: `*size is supposed...` I believe we misunderstood. It's irrelevant what it's "supposed" to be. What is the _actual_ value you are passing to `malloc`? Does `malloc` return `NULL`? `malloc` _will_ return NULL and your program should be prepared for it - as of now, you do not handle that case. Overall, you have to post a full [MCVE] - I doubt will be of much help without a full program.

Comment: I fixed the `reallocate_node_array` to use `realloc` and got rid of the `#define` as suggested by most of you and in @CraigEstey's answer. Now another part of the code is breaking, but I can't make sure it is related. I can't figure it out right at this moment, but later today I'll try to see if I can improve this question, or if the problem is different altogether. I'll be sure to include a minimal working example! Thank you all for all your swift responses.

Comment: Ok, so in the course of working to build a minimum example, I took a long hard look at my code and detected some incredible mistakes and corrected them. For all purposes, the problem I pointed out here is solved. (For those curious, the biggest mistake I made was writing `struct Node * parents;` instead of `struct Node ** parents;` since I need a multiply-linked list). However, from what all of you said, I'm still doing things the bad way. I could modify the question to ask for clarification on those points. Or I could close/delete this, as the solution is unrelated. What do you suggest I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my top comment:

> Where is the call to `reallocate_node_array`? Please *edit* your question and post it. If it's (e.g.): `myarray = reallocate_node_array(myarray,&myarray_size)`, then the original value of `myarray` is leaked (because the function does not free the old/original array pointer). Unless you're trying to create a separate duplicate copy, why not just use realloc? –
> Craig Estey

Your response indicates that this is, indeed, the issue.

So, here is the simple fix:

```
Node *
reallocate_node_array(Node *array, size_t *size)
{

    array = realloc(array,sizeof(*array) * *size * 2);

    if (array == NULL) {
        perror("realloc");
        exit(1);
    }

    *size *= 2;

    return array;
}
```

But, when I see the array size passed as a *separate* parameter, I want to create a new "array" struct that has the size/length in it. This is similar to what a `c++` vector does:

```
typedef struct {
    Node *data;
    size_t size;
} NodeArray;

void
reallocate_node_array(NodeArray *array)
{

    array->data = realloc(array->data,sizeof(*array->data) * array->size * 2);

    if (array->data == NULL) {
        perror("realloc");
        exit(1);
    }

    array->size *= 2;
}
```

---

That's a bit excessive because the *caller* still has to keep track of things.

This is often a exercise for beginning C programmers.

Here's an enhancement:

```
typedef struct {
    Node *data;                         // pointer to data
    size_t size;                        // number of elements currently in use
    size_t capacity;                    // number of elements available
} NodeArray;

void
reallocate_node_array(NodeArray *array,size_t need)
// array -- pointer to node array
// need -- number of elements to grow by
{
    size_t size = array->size + need;

    if (size >= array->capacity) {
        array->capacity = size + 100;
        array->data = realloc(array->data,
            sizeof(*array->data) * array->capacity);

        if (array->data == NULL) {
            perror("realloc");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> You should always assign the result of realloc to a temporary variable - if realloc cannot extend the buffer, it returns NULL but leaves the original buffer in place. If you assign the result back to array->data and it's NULL, then you will have a memory leak. [redacted] –
> John Bode

> JohnBode I know this trick but checking for NULL and exiting is fine too. On most programs/systems, running out of memory is/should be fatal. No way to recover meaningfully. You can handle the error but how does the program progress? –
> Craig Estey

> I think the same way. I never wrote anything where allocating an array was optional. – Coral Bleaching

Yes. As I said, for most programs, it is fatal. The TL;DR is don't worry--be happy as this is one of my "soapbox" issues/nits ;-)

For those programs that do allocations based on some external action (e.g. many clients connecting to a server), the program should/must limit things in *another* way and *not* wait until `malloc/realloc` returns `NULL` when it's "too late" in the process.

For example, it should limit the number of incoming requests that can be processed simultaneously. If we limit to N requests and each request requires M bytes to be allocated, we must know beforehand that `N * M` *can* be allocated safely.

For mission critical, realtime apps usually *all* [possible] allocations are done during program initialization and have various subpools of preallocated structs/buffers. This is what I've done in the past for commercial, product grade apps/systems.

For realtime apps, there is a notion/specification of "real time safe". That is, the program will have "deterministic execution". There are others, but one of its tenets requires that all allocations be done during init to make an out-of-memory condition impossible [by *design*].

Also, when an allocation fails, the program is now in an indeterminate and *unsafe* state. What *else* happened *before* that got us into this state?

Has the allocation failed *just* because it asked for too much memory? That is, did we fail to have enough resource limit checks. This would be a design flaw.

Or, is it because there is a bug [somewhere else] and the heap is corrupted? Or, other parts of the program data/state are now corrupted?

We can't know for sure.

To play it safe, the only thing to do is abort ASAP. Otherwise, what is the *risk* of allowing it to continue when we no longer know what the consequences will be?

(e.g.) Will it [further] corrupt a database or delete the *wrong* file, etc?. The allocation failure may be indicative of UB (undefined behavior) and the consequences are continued operation sending *wrong* values to a realtime control device resulting in *dangerous* behavior of the device. Think: robot control, pacemaker control, etc.

In short, on modern systems, there is usually more than enough memory (e.g. gigabytes) to fulfill all normal requests. So, out-of-memory indicates a *bug* (e.g. runaway loop doing allocations).

Realtime embedded systems that [genuinely] have limited memory have to be carefully crafted beforehand (following the "real time safe" rules/guidelines) to prevent/avoid the condition from ever happening in the first place.

Comment: I forgot to add a `sizeof` to the allocations [now fixed]. So, have a final look. If your `size` parameter was a _node_ count [vs. total byte count], then this is required

Comment: I'll be following your advice from now on. This wasn't *the* issue, but it certainly was an issue. Though I'm curious: is there an alternative to reallocating with `realloc`? If yes, how would one go about it? Should I free my pointer first and call `malloc` after?

Comment: You should always assign the result of `realloc` to a temporary variable - if `realloc` cannot extend the buffer, it returns `NULL` *but leaves the original buffer in place*.  If you assign the result back to `array->data` and it's `NULL`, then you will have a memory leak.  Assign the result to a temporary pointer variable and do not update `array->capacity` until *after* you make sure the `realloc` succeeded - `Node *tmp = realloc( array->data, sizeof *array->data * (size + 100)); if ( tmp ) { array->data = tmp; array->capacity = size + 100; } else { /* handle realloc failure */ }`

Comment: @JohnBode I know this trick but checking for NULL and exiting is fine too. On most programs/systems, running out of memory is/should be fatal. No way to recover meaningfully. You _can_ handle the error but how does the program progress?

Comment: I think the same way. I never wrote anything where allocating an array was optional.